# custom stripe plugin

Tags: php

I am using some code that I found at pippins plugins for integrating stripe into wordpress. I have some custom functions I need to run after a payment is made.  The code works great except for one thing:  When I add a a webhook to stripe it fails with a 302 error.  Here is the code:

```
<?php

function pippin_stripe_event_listener() {

if(isset($_GET['wps-listener']) && $_GET['wps-listener'] == 'stripe') {

    global $stripe_options;

    require_once(STRIPE_BASE_DIR . '/lib/Stripe.php');

    if(isset($stripe_options['test_mode']) && $stripe_options['test_mode']) {
        $secret_key = $stripe_options['test_secret_key'];
    } else {
        $secret_key = $stripe_options['live_secret_key'];
    }

    Stripe::setApiKey($secret_key);

    // retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
    $body = @file_get_contents('php://input');

    // grab the event information
    $event_json = json_decode($body);

    // this will be used to retrieve the event from Stripe
    $event_id = $event_json->id;

    if(isset($event_json->id)) {

        http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater

        try {

            // to verify this is a real event, we re-retrieve the event from Stripe 
            $event = Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);
            $invoice = $event->data->object;

            // successful payment
            if($event->type == 'charge.succeeded') {
                // send a payment receipt email here

                // retrieve the payer's information
                $customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($invoice->customer);
                $email = $customer->email;

                $amount = $invoice->amount / 100; // amount comes in as amount in cents, so we need to convert to dollars

                $subject = __('Payment Receipt', 'pippin_stripe');
                $headers = 'From: "' . html_entity_decode(get_bloginfo('name')) . '" <' . get_bloginfo('admin_email') . '>';
                $message = "Hello " . $customer_name . "\n\n";
                $message .= "You have successfully made a payment of " . $amount . "\n\n";
                $message .= "Thank you.";

                wp_mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
            }

            // failed payment
            if($event->type == 'charge.failed') {
                // send a failed payment notice email here

                // retrieve the payer's information
                $customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($invoice->customer);
                $email = $customer->email;

                $subject = __('Failed Payment', 'pippin_stripe');
                $headers = 'From: "' . html_entity_decode(get_bloginfo('name')) . '" <' . get_bloginfo('admin_email') . '>';
                $message = "Hello " . $customer_name . "\n\n";
                $message .= "We have failed to process your payment of " . $amount . "\n\n";
                $message .= "Please get in touch with support.\n\n";
                $message .= "Thank you.";

                wp_mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // something failed, perhaps log a notice or email the site admin
        }
    }
}
}
add_action('init', 'pippin_stripe_event_listener');
```

and here is my event listener:  (obviously my own domain)

http://domain.com/?wps-listener=stripe

These are the instructions from pippins website, however, these were written in 2012, so maybe something has changed since then. I asked pippin himself, he said others had similar issues but didn't know what the cause was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after 2 days of wasted time, I figured out that since my site was requiring a user login, it was redirecting stripe to the login page.  Now that I removed that function, stripe is able to connect to my site.

Comment: +1 Thanks for taking time to find out, heard same prob this week and your answer solves probably for more ppl the problem. (*Please mark your answer as solution as soon it is possible.*)